# Creating a char/character array list

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am creating a program that gets the seperate letters of a string entered by the user. I want to store my char information in a arraylist, but I am having some issues. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input, output;
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please type sentace to encode: ");
        input = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            characters.add(input.charAt(i)); 
        }
    }

}
```

I have already searched to forums, as I originally put char instead of Character, but now I am getting an error and eclipse wants me to change the jdk to v1.5. What is the issue?

Comment: "I am having some issues". What issues? Show os the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: By the way, here is the error:- Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or 
  greater

Comment: @tomtomy8 r u sure u r using Java 8.

Comment: Have a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr4dca2rxnzm322/Capture01.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

with diamond operator

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Eclipse modifications:**

From the menu bar: Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

Enable project specific settings (checked) Uncheck "use Compliance from execution environment '.... Select the desired "compiler compliance level"

That will allow you to compile "1.5" code using a "1.6" JDK.

If you want to acutally use a 1.5 JDK to produce "1.5" compliant code, then install a suitable 1.5 JDK and tell eclipse where it is installed via:

Window -> preferences -> Installed JREs

And then go back to your project

Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries

remove the 1.6 system libaries, and: add library... -> JRE System LIbrary -> Alternate JRE -> The JRE you want.

Verify that the correct JRE is on the project's build path, save everything, and enjoy!

Comment: All I'm getting is this:                                                     Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
 - '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
 - Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with 
  arguments <>